# How to stop cursor from blinking on Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, preferences, cursor

My MacBook's version is Sonoma 14.0. I hope to disable cursor blinking for as many apps on MacBook as possible, especially for Notes.app, xcode.app, and Safari.app. This question has been asked before [How can I disable the cursor from blinking on a global level](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6720434). But it seems

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOn -float 1000
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOff -float 1000
```

no longer take effect. I tried to quit the app, logged out and logged back in but it still did not work.

Comment: How do you know where it is, and that it's not a | ?